# Balanced when I check model, but imbalanced when I simulate

Tags: modelica, openmodelica

I am trying to simulate the flow in pipes between reservoirs. I have created my own pipe component (based on Modelica.Fluid) and it works fine when I simulate from one tank to another as shown below.

[image]

However, when I try to connect two pipes in series, as shown in the picture below, the model does not work. When I check my model, I'm told my model is balanced and has 402 equations and 402 variables.
However, when I try to simulate I get the following error message:

```
An independent subset of the model has imbalanced number of equations (143) and variables (144)
```

[image]

Any ideas where this error message originates from? How is it possible that a balanced system becomes unbalanced when simulating, and how could it work with one pipe, but not two in series?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The problem is something like:

```
model M
  Real x,y;
equation
  x = sin(x);
  x = 3.0;
end M;
```

Where the total number of equations are balanced, but there is something causing some part of the system to be unbalanced (like forgetting a variable in the equations). OpenModelica internally partitions everything into sets of equations/variables that reach each other, which can give the error-message above. For the trivial cases like the one above, there is usually a different error-message though.